# compile <json/json.h> in eclipse using c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, libjson

I'm trying to include and compile

```
#include <json/json.h>
```

However even though I've installed it and included it on the project settings it wouldn't find the path.

here's what I've so far done:

path to libjson:

```
 /usr/include/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0
```

options in eclipse  gcc c++ compiler:

```
-Ijson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -ljson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt
```

libraries in gcc c++ linker:

```
-L/usr/include/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/include/
```

Anything else I forgot to do to make it work?

Comment: It would help if you put up an error message

Comment: It says in an error style next to the include line that theres no such file or directory so I guess it's my path that is wrong ... I dont quite know hot to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding -I/usr/include/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0 to compiler options

Comment: I did..the outputs the same..the compile command is g++ -Ijson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt -I/usr/include/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Ijson_linux-gcc-4.5.2_libmt -MMD -MP -MF"src/libparser.d" -MT"src/libparser.d" -o"src/libparser.o"

Comment: You might want to search json.h on your file system. First check if it exists. I would use " find /usr/include -name "json.h" " to locate it. If it is at for example /usr/include/some/path/json/json.h then you will need to add -I/usr/include/some/path in compiler option.

Comment: result is /usr/include/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/include/json/json.h

Comment: then add -I/usr/include/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/include

Comment: Yeah I figured thats what you meant..Worked like charm...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

-L indicates where to find shared libraries (e.g. .so)

-I is the search path for the header files.

If the problem occurs during compilation (json.h not found), then you have indicated the wrong -I

If it occurs during linking (symbol not found), then you have indicated a wrong -L, a wrong -l, or forgot to run ldconfig